# How can I draw multiple lines connected via “nodes” in winforms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, line, graphic

I'm writing dijkstra algorithm i want to draw lines between each two nodes that connect two nodes with each other i am writing code but it just draw one line between two nodes.i wanna each time that i click on two node it created line.of course , i am using `"DrawLines()"` Method but it just create one line.

[image]

```
    public class Graph
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>> vertices = new Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>>();

    public void AddVertex(int id, List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> edges)
    {
        if (!vertices.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            vertices.Add(id, new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>());
        }
        vertices[id].AddRange(edges);
    }

}
```

---

```
    private CircleManager circleManager = new CircleManager();
    private List<Circle> circlesSourceAndDestination = new List<Circle>();
    private Graph g = new Graph();
    private int lastClickedNode = -1;

        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pic_Paint);
    }

    private void pic_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        DrawCircles(g);
        DrawLines(g);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This method specifies neighbors of node
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private int currentNode = 0;

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            //Name of node in variable result. for example : 0 or 1 ,...
            var result = circleManager.HitTest(e.Location);

            //node doesn't should be negative
            if (result != -1)
            {
                circlesSourceAndDestination.Add(circleManager.Circles[result]);

                if (lastClickedNode == -1)
                {
                    lastClickedNode = result;
                    return;
                }

                var weigth = CalculateLengthSourceAndDestination(circlesSourceAndDestination);
                circlesSourceAndDestination.Clear();
                if (weigth < 0)
                {
                    weigth *= -1;
                }
                int secondNode = result;
                var neighbor = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(secondNode, weigth);
                var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> { neighbor };
                g.AddVertex(lastClickedNode, list);

                var nodes = g;
                ExtractNodes(nodes);
                //DrawLines(points);
                lastClickedNode = -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var result = circleManager.HitTest(e.Location);
            if (result != -1)
            {
                circleManager.Circles[circleManager.HitTest(e.Location)].Selected = true;
                circleManager.Circles[result].SelectFillColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private List<Point> pnt = new List<Point>();

    private void ExtractNodes(Graph nodes)
    {
        foreach (var item in nodes.vertices)
        {
            foreach (var circle in circleManager.Circles)
            {
                if (item.Key == Convert.ToInt32(circle.Name) && pnt.Count == 0)
                {
                    pnt.Add(circle.Location);
                }

                ExtractNodesTwo(item.Value);
                if (pnt.Count == 2)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ExtractNodesTwo(List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> value)
    {
        if (pnt.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in circleManager.Circles)
            {
                foreach (var val in value)
                {
                    if (val.Key == Convert.ToInt32(item.Name))
                    {
                        pnt.Add(item.Location);
                    }
                }

                if (pnt.Count == 2)
                    return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void DrawLines(Graphics g)
    {
        if (pnt.Count == 2)
        {
            LinearGradientBrush liner =
                         new LinearGradientBrush(pnt[0], pnt[1],
                     Color.Transparent,
                         Color.Black);
            Pen pen = new Pen(liner);
            g.DrawLines(pen, pnt.ToArray());

            pnt.Clear();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Many other errors/issues there. About the problem you're asking for...if (pnt.Count == 2...)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, "pnt.Count == 2" is keeping location two nodes that selected first nodes and second node that is clicked.

Comment: Then where do you drive all the lines?

Comment: I am drawing lines in "DrawLines()" method.

Comment: In `MouseDoubleClick` what is `Location`? In  `MouseClick` what is `g` ? In `DrawLines` why not `g.DrawLines(pen, pnt.ToArray());` ? Also there : You miss 2 `using` clauses. Where do you store the lines to draw? You could use the `pnt` List and connect every other point; atm you always clear it..

Comment: @Alex I see, it was a retoric question...no, you are NOT. you're drawing a single line. Put a breakpoint and see what happens there...

Comment: @alexshiro, You should remove some code which is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @TaW,I updated my code,i am storing two nodes into "pnt" for first node and second node after that draw line i am clearing "pnt" for getting two  other nodes point

Comment: @TaW, I get it , after that create nodes for example four nodes , i put a breakpoint in pic_Paint event , when i clicked on nodes no longer active breakpoint in pic_Paint event in fact,pic_Paint doesn't work when click nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling DrawLines(Graphics g) method only once when paint method is called. This implies that you want to draw all the lines in this method only. But, **`g.DrawLines(pen, sd);` is not in any loop.** **So, it can draw only one line** when executed.

I think `g.DrawLines(pen, sd);` should be in some kind of loop which iterates 'n' no of times(where n is number of lines you want to draw).

Comment: because i use DrawLines() method i can't access directly to pic_paint event how can i put DrawLines() method in loop.